# Why do I get a type error in model.predictOnValues when I try the official example of Streaming Kmeans Clustering of Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying the Streaming Clustering example code [at the end of the official guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/mllib-clustering.html#examples-1), but I get a type error. Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.StreamingKMeans

object Kmeans {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("kmeans")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(3))

    val trainingData = ssc.textFileStream("training").map(Vectors.parse)
    val testData = ssc.textFileStream("test").map(LabeledPoint.parse)

    val numDimensions = 3
    val numClusters = 2
    val model = new StreamingKMeans()
      .setK(numClusters)
      .setDecayFactor(1.0)
      .setRandomCenters(numDimensions, 0.0)

    model.trainOn(trainingData)
    model.predictOnValues(testData).print()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

But when I run

```
sbt package
```

I get the following error:

```
[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint]
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[(?, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)]
[error]     model.predictOnValues(testData).print()
[error]                           ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map `testData: DStream[LabeledPoint]` to a `DStream[(K, Vector)]`:

```
model.predictOnValues(testData.map(lp => (lp.label, lp.features))).print()
```

You can find the complete example here: [StreamingKMeansExample.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/StreamingKMeansExample.scala)